# How to do a git add in Bluemix?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

Editing a project in Bluemix. I understand how to do commits and pushes in that environment. I do not see an option for doing an add. Is it there and I'm just not seeing it? Or do I have to clone the project to my local machine and do my adds and other git commands there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bluemix UI recently changed.  If you are looking for the Add git button that was available before, you may now find a link on your application dashboard overview tab. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the browser-based DevOps Services to edit your code? If so, all new files you create should show up in the Working Directory Changes section. You can select them and commit, which is equivalent to got a git add and commit.

https://hub.jazz.net/docs/git/#commit_files_to_the_remote_branch

Answer (score 0):

You will see "Add a git code" on your project's dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I get it now. It looks like there's not a separate add. You just commit, and then push, and the new file magically shows up in the master.